# like operator issue in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-like

```
declare @CustField6 nvarchar(10)
declare @sample nvarchar(10)
set @CustField6 = 'sf'

select customer_id  from csu_customer_policy
    inner join csu_policy on csu_policy.policy_number = csu_customer_policy.policy_number
    and csu_policy.data_source = csu_customer_policy.data_source
    where csu_policy.vehicle_no like  + '''' + @CustField6 + '%''' and csu_customer_policy.delete_status = 0 and csu_customer_policy.site_id = 1
```

I want all the records who have `csu_policy.vehicle_no` starts with `sf%`

if I give the value `sf` directly instead  of  `@CustField6` it gives all my records but when I execute this by using `@CustField6` it does not give any error but retrieves no records, even I printed this code to check if the query is correctly being framed, and it is working fine. But I don't know why it is not retrieving any records?

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax is incorrect. It should be:

```
where csu_policy.vehicle_no like @CustField6 + '%'
```

Assuming that `@CustField6` is equal to `sf`, this is equivalent to

```
where csu_policy.vehicle_no like 'sf%'
```

If you do this:

```
where csu_policy.vehicle_no like ''''  + @CustField6 + '%''''
```

Then you are actually doing this:

```
where csu_policy.vehicle_no like '''sf%'''
```

In other words, you're finding records that match `'sf%'` - records that start with a quote, then `sf`, then anything, then end with a quote.

Comment: when ever we specify value for like it should be in single quotes right? that is the reason its framed like that,if i give what you told it is retreiving records whose vehicle no's are "sjrt45','sghfg78' also

Comment: if @CustField6 is equal to `sf`, then the above is equivalent to `like 'sf%'`. Is that the result you want?

Answer (score 1):

Change your criteria to:

```
WHERE csu_policy.vehicle_no LIKE @CustField6 + '%'
```

Demo:  [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1fa93/7854/0)

Answer (score 0):

I think the trouble with your query is that you have a few to many `'` and `+` in your where condition:
It should be `where csu_policy.data_source like @custField6 + '%'` instead of the `csu_policy.vehicle_no like  + '''' + @CustField6 + '%'''`

```
declare @CustField6 nvarchar(10) 
declare @sample nvarchar(10) 
set @CustField6 = 'sf'

select customer_id 
from csu_customer_policy 
inner join csu_policy on csu_policy.policy_number = csu_customer_policy.policy_number 
      and csu_policy.data_source = csu_customer_policy.data_source 
where csu_policy.vehicle_no like @CustField6 + '%' 
and csu_customer_policy.delete_status = 0 and csu_customer_policy.site_id = 1
```

Comment: when ever we specify value for like it should be in single quotes right? that is the reason its framed like that,if i give what you told it is retreiving records whose vehicle no's are "sjrt45','sghfg78' also

Comment: the only thing the @CustField6 + '%' is doing is creating a string which is concatenated from 'sf' + '%' so the result would be interpreted as 'sf%' the quotes in SQL are used because the like operator requires input in the form of a string.

Answer (score 0):

Try get rid +

```
from
 csu_policy.vehicle_no like + '''' + @CustField6 + '%'''

To
 csu_policy.vehicle_no like  ''''+ @CustField6 + '%'''
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the unwanted quotes.. Try this.

```
declare @CustField6 nvarchar(10)
declare @sample nvarchar(10)
set @CustField6 = 'sf'

select customer_id  from csu_customer_policy
    inner join csu_policy on csu_policy.policy_number = csu_customer_policy.policy_number
    and csu_policy.data_source = csu_customer_policy.data_source
    where (csu_policy.vehicle_no like  + '' + @CustField6 + '%') and    
           csu_customer_policy.delete_status = 0 and 
           csu_customer_policy.site_id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, use single quote as per below :

```
declare @CustField6 nvarchar(10)
declare @sample nvarchar(10)
set @CustField6 = 'sf'

select customer_id  from csu_customer_policy
    inner join csu_policy on csu_policy.policy_number = csu_customer_policy.policy_number
    and csu_policy.data_source = csu_customer_policy.data_source
    where csu_policy.vehicle_no like  '' + @CustField6 + '%' and csu_customer_policy.delete_status = 0 and csu_customer_policy.site_id = 1
```